# Iterating a limited number of elements from an array

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a function that takes a string that contains three types of elements:
A char value that can be `F` or `B` followed by an integer that represents a day and another integer that represents the sales or payments made depending if it has the letter `F` or `B` before the day value, the function should return all the days on which the value of the `sales` is not equal to the sum of up to 4 payments made in the day or in the days after (for example `F 1 100 F 2 50 B 2 25 B 3 25` returns 1). Since I cannot use equal payment values on different sale values what I did was to put the numbers from the `sales` on one array and the numbers from the `payments` on another one and then comparing them using `for` cycles, what I did was to compare the sale value with the payment value (first checking if the day of the payment is equal or larger than then sale day), if it's not equal i add to the payment value the value from the next day and so on, up until the 3 next payment values, once the sale value matches the sum of one, two, three or four payment values I replace them with zero on both arrays, at the end I filter all the days that do not have zero as value in the `sales` array and return them, but the problem with this is that it only takes into consideration elements next to each other on the `payments` array. So I don't know how to limit the number of elements from the payments array that can be sum to compare it with the sales array values.

```
const bakery = (input) => {
    const table = input.split(' ')
    const sales = []
    const payments = []
    //I separate the numbers into two arrays
    for(i=0;i<table.length/3;i++){
        table[3*i]==='F'?
        sales.push([table[3*i+1],Number(table[3*i+2])]):
        payments.push([table[3*i+1],Number(table[3*i+2])])
    }
    for(i=0;i<sales.length;i++){
        for(j=0;j<payments.length;j++){
            //here I compare every value of the sales array with one, two, three or four
            //values of the payments array, the problem is that they don't have to necessarily consecutive
           //If the 4 first elements don't match I can also use the 5th or 6th element
          //as long as I use only 4 elements in the comparison so I'm not sure how to limit that
            const second = payments[j+1]?payments[j+1][1]:0
            const third = payments[j+2]?payments[j+2][1]:0
            const fourth = payments[j+3]?payments[j+3][1]:0

           if(payments[j][0]>=sales[i][0]){
            if(sales[i][1]===payments[j][1]){
                sales[i][1]=0
                payments[j][1]=0
           }else{
           if(sales[i][1]===payments[j][1]+second){
                sales[i][1]=0
                payments[j][1]=0
                payments[j+1][1]=0
            }else{
                if(sales[i][1]===payments[j][1]+third){
                    sales[i][1]=0
                    payments[j][1]=0
                    payments[j+2][1]=0
                }else{
                    if(sales[i][1]===payments[j][1]+fourth){
                        sales[i][1]=0
                        payments[j][1]=0
                        payments[j+3][1]=0
                    }else{
                        if(sales[i][1]===payments[j][1]+second+fourth){
                            sales[i][1]=0
                            payments[j+1][1]=0
                            payments[j+3][1]=0
                        }else{
                            if(sales[i][1]===payments[j][1]+third+fourth){
                                sales[i][1]=0
                                payments[j+2][1]=0
                                payments[j+3][1]=0
                            }else{
                                if(sales[i][1]===payments[j][1]+second+third+fourth){
                                    sales[i][1]=0
                                    payments[j+1][1]=0
                                    payments[j+2][1]=0
                                    payments[j+3][1]=0
                                }
                             }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
           }
           }
        }
    }
    //at the end i filter all the days that have zero as values in the sales array
    const missing = sales.filter(sale => sale[1]!==0)
    return missing.map(day=>day[0]).join(' ')

}
```

The function works with

```
console.log(bakery('F 1 209 F 2 254 F 3 895 F 4 439 B 1 104 B 2 127 B 3 74 B 3 447 B 4 127 B 4 219 B 5 448 B 6 220'))
console.log(bakery('F 1 367 F 2 38 F 3 602 F 4 624 B 1 183 B 2 19 B 3 184 B 3 301 B 4 19 B 4 312 B 5 64 B 6 312'))
console.log(bakery('F 1 995 F 2 884 F 3 749 F 4 866 B 1 497 B 2 442 B 3 319 B 3 374 B 4 239 B 4 433 B 5 375 B 6 177'))
```

The function does not work with

```
console.log(bakery('F 1 123395 F 2 488034 F 3 78861 F 4 200882 F 5 102517 F 6 49658 F 7 201804 F 8 247860 F 9 356333 F 10 163982 F 11 351283 F 12 305592 F 13 443860 F 14 111094 F 15 216152 F 17 220897 F 16 184823 F 19 438974 F 18 464208 B 1 61697 B 2 9577 B 2 244017 B 3 30849 B 3 39430 B 4 244017 B 4 19716 B 4 100441 B 5 19715 B 5 51258 B 6 100441 B 6 25630 B 6 24829 B 7 25629 B 7 100902 B 8 24829 B 8 123930 B 9 100902 B 9 61965 B 9 178166 B 10 61965 B 10 89084 B 10 81991 B 11 89083 B 11 175641 B 12 81991 B 12 152796 B 13 175642 B 13 76398 B 13 221930 B 14 76398 B 14 110965 B 14 55547 B 15 110965 B 15 27774 B 15 108076 B 17 73709 B 17 46206 B 17 110448 B 16 27773 B 16 92411 B 19 110449 B 19 116052 B 19 219487 B 18 46206 B 18 232104 B 21 219487 B 20 116052'))
```

Comment: do you have some small examples and the wanted results? and please add some linefeeds.

Comment: also, `bank` is not defined in your sample

Comment: @NinaScholz yes, i have added three working examples

Comment: do you want only three or four payments? or days with payments? do earlier sales goes first, if possible? please add the wanted results as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz i can use up until four payments values and the days of those payments have to be equal or greater than the day of the sale value